# When did the colloquial "bro" come into use?

Tags: etymology

I did research and came up with nothing.  It only shows "brother".  I'm talking about "bro" as a colloquialism, when reffering to a guy, like saying "dude".  For example:

> Pass the chips, bro.
>
> Hey bro; you coming to the party later?

Comment: I can get you to 1962. (https://books.google.com/books?id=r2TQPNTBbAsC&pg=PA27&dq=%22bro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWoMn42MfOAhXIdR4KHfW8DoE4MhDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22bro%22&f=false) Random House can get you to 1839.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bro) the expression "bro" as a short for brother  dates back to 1830-40, but it is only arond the mid-20th century that "bro" began to be used outside the familiar or religious contexts:

The following extract from [Oxfordwords.blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/10/the-rise-of-the-portmanbro/) traces its origin and its more recent semantic changes:

> - ***For centuries, it was merely a graphic abbreviation of brother (properly bro.), occasionally put to colloquial use, like sis, to refer to a person’s male sibling.***
> - ***It wasn’t until the 20th century that bro’s meaning began to stray from familial relationships and religious titles.***  More recently still, the word has taken on new life as a productive element forming new words and compounds, like brogrammer (a loutish male computer programmer), or curlbro (a gym rat who focuses too much attention on his biceps).
> - Bro’s meaning had begun to expand by the mid-20th century. ***It came to refer simply to a man (a synonym of ‘fellow’ or ‘guy’), or sometimes more specifically a black man. The rock critic Lester Bangs wrote in 1976, “if we the (presumably) white jass-buffs couldn’t get with it maybe it was only meant for the bros.”***
> - Bro also became common as a term of direct address (“Hey, bro!”). ***These developments gave bro a bigger semantic footprint, but they didn’t completely sever the tie with brother, which had been used in similar ways even earlier.***